# Why does git log not show in chronological order, and code has been deleted?

Tags: git, git-branch

We are having a strange issue with our git branch that I'm hoping is more about our understanding, than a problem as such. I will describe our workflow the best I can to make sure we're not missing something obvious:

One of the team made a branch with `git checkout -b newproject`, then made a few changes, then pushed those changes with `git push -u origin new project`. Then other developers joined the project, using `git fetch origin` and then `git checkout newproject`.

Next, the workflow is as follows. Developers make changes, `git add` the new and modified files, and `git commit` periodically. Then when they want everyone else to see their changes, they will do a `git pull origin newproject` to get any changes since the last pull, followed by a `git push -u origin newproject`.

**Note:** In `/etc/gitconfig` we have the following:

```
[branch]
autosetuprebase = always
```

Often we'll get conflicts when `pull`ing, as we're working on the same files a lot. When we do, we get the instruction to manually resolve the conflicts then run `git rebase --continue` We open the files, select the code we want to keep and make necessary changes and save. Then, we `git add filename.ext` when they're resolved, then run `git rebase --continue`. After this has finished, with `git status` showing there are no changes, on the `newproject` branch and ahead by X commits, we use `git push -u origin newproject`.

We noticed this morning that large chunks of code suddenly went missing. When running `git log`, the first thing we noticed was that it wasn't in chronological order, [as the manual suggests](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_commit_ordering).

```
commit bc0903fc5795425908f335cebcab11055869d75d
Author: billy <billy@our.biz>
Date:   Thu Sep 11 15:29:37 2014 +0100

    Add responsive skin to sectionProducts

commit 7833850313c2974c3b8cbc75383b1834fbf4bf93
Author: bob <bob@our.biz>
Date:   Thu Sep 11 14:44:37 2014 +0100

    Rewrite the way breadcrumbs are generated and output to the page

commit 09d1318d9e7249e9e45826d7ddc33f23fc5974b1
Author: bob <bob@our.biz>
Date:   Thu Sep 11 11:25:21 2014 +0100

    Fix styles for video and featured product boxes, fix miscellaneous bugs and remove obselete code

commit 13f01644935092b490be55b6738f500f0f5fcb2e
Author: bob <bob@our.biz>
Date:   Thu Sep 11 08:31:03 2014 +0100

    Fix section.html, add featured products, star buy products and product videos

commit 01b3bfb3c20f74ea437b221711deabc970f670d8
Author: bob <bob@our.biz>
Date:   Fri Sep 12 08:45:19 2014 +0100

    Refine code for breadcrumbs

commit 0303bae79f7ff2e84221e0db3f88d3630d4afa91
Author: bob <bob@our.biz>
Date:   Thu Sep 11 15:53:06 2014 +0100

    Modify getBreadcrumbTrail so that it attempts to take the correct route when recursing

commit 1ae5f00814bf216eda5449a6e8d89123b124fad8
Author: bob <bob@our.biz>
Date:   Thu Sep 11 14:44:37 2014 +0100

    Rewrite the way breadcrumbs are generated and output to the page
```

It also appears some commits are repeated. Another point to note is that one of the developers mentioned that when they saw some conflicts and resolved them, then ran `git rebase --continue`, they were shown another list of conflicts. This happened a few times before they were all resolved, before being able to push.

**Update:** We've noticed that the issues is a little more explainable that initially thought. Right up until, and including, when **bob** pushed his commits, up to commit `01b3bfb3c20f74ea437b221711deabc970f670d8` with date `Fri Sep 12 08:45:19 2014 +0100`, everything was correct. It was chronologically ordered and the code was correct. The next 3 commits by **bob** are in fact the same 3 commits before the commit I just mentioned, and were added when **billy** pushed his changes. So, they are **bob**'s commits, but somehow re-added by **billy**. Also notice that the final commit wasn't re-added, which is where the bulk of the problems seem to stem from.

To illustrator this a little better I present the following:

```
87e9a4e Add sectionGroup.html to templates_safelincs
bc0903f Add responsive skin to sectionProducts
7833850 Rewrite the way breadcrumbs are generated and output to the page
09d1318 Fix styles for video and featured product boxes, fix miscellaneous bugs and remove obselete code
13f0164 Fix section.html, add featured products, star buy products and product videos
01b3bfb Refine code for breadcrumbs
0303bae Modify getBreadcrumbTrail so that it attempts to take the correct route when recursing
1ae5f00 Rewrite the way breadcrumbs are generated and output to the page
2cc0525 Fix styles for video and featured product boxes, fix miscellaneous bugs and remove obselete code
cc3c86b Fix section.html, add featured products, star buy products and product videos
```

Can anyone explain what we're doing wrong here?

Comment: There's information missing (so can't say precisely what happened) but note that when you `git rebase`, you *copy* commits (then abandon the originals in favor of the new copies).  If you rebase only your *own*, un-pushed, commits, no one else has your old versions, but if you somehow rebase someone *else*'s (pushed/published) commits, you copy *theirs* too.  This is almost certainly what happened.  To get both copies into the history you can then merge your copies with theirs (this will show up in `--graph` output or with gitk, etc).

Comment: It certainly seems that this could be valid. Is there any more information I can provide to help you give me a starting point on where to look? I'm a little lost. P.S. `--graph` output just shows one linear path.

Comment: Really need to know what each individual user did, or have/see lots of logs from the server.  As for the date ordering, note that there are *two* time-stamps on each commit: author date and committer date.  The log-sort defaults to using the commit date while the `medium` format shows you the author date (only).  (When using `--graph`, the log sort is forced to `--topo-order`.)

Comment: you guys do a rebase whenever you get conflicts on a pull?  why not `git mergetool`?

Comment: @LeonardChallis: It is expected that --graph will show a linear history if you are always rebasing. [The manual] has some good reading on `rebase` that should clarify this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For completeness, I'll post the reason here.

Simply put, we were rewriting public history, [which is bad](http://git-scm.com/book/ch3-6.html#The-Perils-of-Rebasing). What we do *now* is rebase from master to our feature branch only, and when it's up to date with our own commits applied at the head, we then merge in to master. We've also started squelching the commits too, actually. Even though we may make the initial commit a few weeks ago.

Answer (score 0):

I think this sequence will produce the graph you're seeing:

1. bob pushes three commits not shown, call them a,b,c, whose parent is `cc3^`
2. billy `pull --rebase`'s his work on top of them, but decides not to push anything yet
3. bob for some reason goes back and redoes those three commits, producing `cc3`, `2cc` and `1ae` as the new a,b,c, and continues with `030` and `01b`.
4. bob force-pushes this new history, which diverges from billy's at `cc3^`
5. billy now `pull --rebase`s again. so a,b,c and two more commits get rebased onto `01b`, getting `13f`,`09d`,`783` as his newly-rebased versions of Bob's original a,b,c and his own `bc0` and `87e`.

Answer (score 0):

Please see `git reflog show` command. It helped me recover my local commits.